# (GitKraken) Pre-commit Failed Exit Code: 1

Tags: git, exit-code, pre-commit-hook, gitkraken, pre-commit

I'm using GitKraken (not sure if relevant) and as I'm trying to commit, I get this error message:
[image]

And as I press the button "View Hook Output" I get the following:

pre-commit

husky > npm run -s precommit (node v8.9.4)[?25l

npm > Running tasks for src/**/*.js

\ yarn format
    git add
(...lots of these two rows...)
\ yarn format
    git add

"yarn format" found some errors. Please fix them and try committing again.
yarn run v1.6.0
$ prettier-standard './src/**/*.js' C:\mypath\myfile.js
info[Visit [0;1mhttps://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this comand.

prettier-eslint [ERROR] eslint fix failed due to an eslint error
prettier-standard [ERROR] There was an error formatting "C:\mypath\messages.js":
TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of null

```
at SourceCode.getTokenBefore (c:\mypath\index.js:303:18)
at checkSpacingBefore (C:\mypath\template-curly-spacing.js:52:42)
at TemplateElement (C:\mypath\template-curly-spacing.js:117:17)
at listeners.(anonymous function).forEach.listener (C:\mypath\safe-emitter.js:47:58)
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at Object.emit (C:\mypath\safe-emitter.js:47:38)
at NodeEventGenerator.applySelector (C:\mypath\node_modules\eslint\lib\utilode-event-generator.js:251:26)
at NodeEventGenerator.applySelectors (C:\mypath\node_modules\eslint\lib\util\node-event-generator.js:280:22)
at NodeEventGenerator.enterNode (C:\mypath\node-event-generator.js:294:14)
at CodePathAnalyzer.enterNode (C:\mypath\code-path-analyzer.js:608:23)
at Traverser.enter [as _enter] (C:\mypath\node_modules\eslint\lib\linter.js:865:28)
at Traverser._traverse (C:\mypath\traverser.js:132:14)
at Traverser._traverse (C:\mypath\node_modules\eslint\lib\util\traverser.js:144:34)
at Traverser._traverse (C:\mypath\node_modules\eslint\lib\util\traverser.js:147:30)
at Traverser._traverse (C:\mypath\traverser.js:144:34)
at Traverser._traverse (C:\mypath\traverser.js:147:30)
```

failure formatting 1 file with prettier-standard
error Command failed with exit code 1.

husky > pre-commit hook failed (add --no-verify to bypass)
exit

What is causing this? No one can commit anything on GitKraken or Sourcetree. Only on command line. Very strange. What might be the cause and solution to this?
I've heard some comments about npm versions used by husky or yarn.

Comment: You *are* able to commit via command line? Is there a file named `pre-commit` in the repositorys `.git/hooks` folder? Can you post its contents?

Answer (score 3):

From GitKraken:

Some advanced hooks may rely on features not included in GitKraken's bundled minimal Git install. You can select a full Git install for GitKraken to use from Preferences > Experimental > Git Executable after downloading and installing Git from https://git-scm.com/download/win.

Comment: This actually fixed my git hook that ran a command using husky+npx. I had no clue as to why it was failing only in GitKraken but not from CLI or VS Code but this explains it

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue but managed to temporarily fix it by removing the precommit npm module, be mind full this is not the ideal way as precommit runs the test scripts before the code is pushed to your repository.

use below command to remove recommit.
npm remove precommit

Answer (score 0):

I recently just solved this on a nodejs project i forked from by removing anything precommit was.

- .Git/hooks/
- package.json
- node_modules

Using visual studio you need to be in solution explorer and show all files otherwise they will be hidden.