# Resolve pre-commit error ignoring NAME extension

Tags: gitlab, githooks, gitkraken

** Scenario:**

- I am using `gitkraken` to commit my source and instantly get a pre-commit error

  > ignoring NAME extension

** Todo:**

- Fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

If this is a [pre-commit hook](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_pre_commit) error, check your repo for a `.git/hooks/pre-commit` executable file, which could have been generated by GitKraken.

If you have such a file, try and rename it for testing, and see if you can commit.

The [`git commit --no-verify` option to skip any pre-commit hook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7230886/6309) would not work with GitKraken, as [illustrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50332953/6309).

Comment: There is a --no-verify option that can be added to a few git commands, so hooks can be bypassed.

Comment: @Lovato Yes, I mentioned as much in 2011: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7230886/6309. But I don't think that could apply to GitKraken.

Comment: Got it. There are a few bug reports saying that this feature does exist, but not behaving very well.

Comment: @Lovato do you have URLs referencing those bug reports?

Comment: Search for ~ gitkraken "no verify" ~ on google. There are several links.